# Cannot change UIView background colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicolor

I have an iOS app which contains a UIView and a sub UIView in my ViewController. (Created in Storyboard).

I want to change the background colour of the subview in an IBAction but the app just crashes. Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)open_popup {
   [popupView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:255 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
}
```

**Update - This is how I have declared the popup view**

```
IBOutlet UIView *popupView; // in my header file
```

**Update - Here is the error I am getting**

```
2014-08-02 18:20:39.009 ZenApp[1373:60b] 4 
2014-08-02 18:20:39.011 ZenApp[1373:60b] -[NSCFType CGColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c896a60 
2014-08-02 18:20:39.015 ZenApp[1373:60b] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType CGColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c896a60' * 

First throw call stack: ( 
0 CoreFoundation 0x0000000101f05495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165 
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000101c6499e objc_exception_throw + 43 
2 CoreFoundation 0x0000000101f9665d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205 
3 CoreFoundation 0x0000000101ef6d8d ___forwarding_ + 973 
4 CoreFoundation 0x0000000101ef6938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120 
5 UIKit 0x000000010086466c -[UIView(Hierarchy) _setBackgroundColor:] + 37 
6 ZenApp 0x00000001000036f8 -[ViewController change_colour_stage_4] + 168 
7 ZenApp 0x0000000100002e5d -[ViewController change_colours] + 205 
8 ZenApp 0x00000001000030db -[ViewController change_colour_stage_1] + 587 
9 ZenApp 0x0000000100002d17 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 3079 
10 UIKit 0x000000010090759e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 562 
11 UIKit 0x0000000100907777 -[UIViewController view] + 29 
12 UIKit 0x00000001008502d2 -[UIWindow handleStatusBarChangeFromHeight:toHeight:] + 530 
13 UIKit 0x0000000100851ca6 +[UIWindow _noteStatusBarHeightChanged:oldHeight:forAutolayoutRootViewsOnly:] + 230 
14 UIKit 0x000000010086a92f +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 460 
15 UIKit 0x000000010086abc5 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:animations:completion:] + 59 
16 UIKit 0x0000000100813bf5 -[UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:] + 478 
17 UIKit 0x0000000100847c33 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 221 
18 UIKit 0x0000000100850ffa -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 51 
19 UIKit 0x000000010080cc98 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1788 
20 UIKit 0x0000000100810a0c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 660 
21 UIKit 0x0000000100821d4c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3189 
22 UIKit 0x0000000100822216 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79 
23 UIKit 0x0000000100812086 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 578 
24 GraphicsServices 0x000000010386671a _PurpleEventCallback + 762 
25 GraphicsServices 0x00000001038661e1 PurpleEventCallback + 35 
26 CoreFoundation 0x0000000101e87679 CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 41 
27 CoreFoundation 0x0000000101e8744e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478 
28 CoreFoundation 0x0000000101eb0903 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939 
29 CoreFoundation 0x0000000101eafd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467 
30 UIKit 0x00000001008102e1 -[UIApplication _run] + 609 
31 UIKit 0x0000000100811e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010 
32 ZenApp 0x0000000100004413 main + 115 
33 libdyld.dylib 0x00000001034e65fd start + 1 
34 ??? 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)
```

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: Well.. what does the console show when it crashes? There is your first clue.

Comment: Make sure popupView really is pointing to a UIView.

Comment: @Tander I have updated my question with the error I am getting. Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: @Anna What do you mean exactly? If you mean in terms of interface builder and the referencing outlet then yes it is connected.

Comment: I cannot read the stacktrace and I cannot be bothered to edit it.  Please sort it out.

Comment: Irrelevant to your question; that's not the way to set color. If you want full color in a channel set it to `1.0` not `255`. And if you want `Red:120` do `120.0/255`

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Is popupView definitely a UIView object? How is it declared? I find it odd that you're accessing it's instance variable directly and not the property.

Comment: @Tander Yes it is. I have declared it in the header like so: IBOutlet UIView *popupView;

Comment: Try something like `NSLog(@"View: %@", NSStringFromClass([popupView class]));` right before you set the background color and see what it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well I tried @Tander solution but then Xcode suggested I access the UIView like this: "->" and then it worked.... I'm not sure why though. If anyone knows, I would be grateful if you could explain why it works this way.

Old code:

```
[popupView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:255/255 blue:0/255 alpha:1.0]];
```

New code:

```
[self->popupView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:255/255 blue:0/255 alpha:1.0]];
```

This did the trick.

Comment: @Tander Apparently it works this way. Do you happen to know why?

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace shows this:

> 2 CoreFoundation 0x0000000101f9665d -[NSObject(NSObject)
>   doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205  3 CoreFoundation 0x0000000101ef6d8d
>   ___forwarding_ + 973  4 CoreFoundation 0x0000000101ef6938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5 UIKit 0x000000010086466c -[UIView(Hierarchy) _setBackgroundColor:] + 37

Which means `popupView` has no idea what `setBackgroundColor` is. (doesNotRecognizeSelector)

Check and make sure that popupView is actually a valid UIView  object.

Comment: I have declared it like this: IBOutlet UIView *popupView; in my header file. So this should not be the issue.

Comment: then why are you accessing its backing instance directly? why not self.popUpView ?

Comment: I suspect there is the issue. Type in self.popUpView and just see what happens then?

Comment: @tander It's not a property , it's an Ivar

Comment: I get the error: "popupView not found on object of type 'ViewController *' did you mean to access instance variable 'popupView'?

Comment: Oh, sorry I thought you declared it as a property. Not an ivar. I stand corrected.

Comment: What happens when you set it like this:                            popupView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

Answer (score 0):

Even you can set the image as background as shown below:

1. For color
   `popupView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:255 blue:0 alpha:1.0];`
2. For set the Image as background:
   `popupView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.png"]];`